# Keras LSTM ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer lstm_24: expected ndim=3, found ndim=4

Tags: keras, lstm

I am trying to test an architecture I want to use on a video problem. I am simulating 1 video, 24 frames, 240x320x3. I am not getting dimensions right but I can't see it.

```
vid = np.ndarray((24,240,320,3),np.uint8)
vid = np.ndarray((24,240,320,3),np.uint8)
vid = np.random.randint(0, 255, (24,240,320,3),np.uint8)


nrows = vid.shape[1]
ncols = vid.shape[2]
batch_size = 32
num_classes = 1
epochs = 60

nframes = len(vid)
nchan = 3


model = Sequential()
model.image_dim_ordering = 'tf'
model.image_data_format = 'tf'

model = Sequential([
    TimeDistributed(Dense(nrows*ncols, activation='softmax'), 
                    input_shape=(nrows,ncols,nchan)),
    LSTM((nrows,ncols), recurrent_dropout=0.2, dropout=0.2,             
    return_sequences=True),
    Dense(1),
    Activation('sigmoid')
])
```

get the error:

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-31-a0219d8eece3> in <module>()
     41     LSTM((nrows,ncols), recurrent_dropout=0.2, dropout=0.2, return_sequences=True),
     42     Dense(1),
---> 43     Activation('sigmoid')
     44 ])
     45 

C:\Users\david\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\keras\models.py in __init__(self, layers, name)
    396         if layers:
    397             for layer in layers:
--> 398                 self.add(layer)
    399 
    400     def add(self, layer):
C:\Users\david\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\keras\models.py in add(self, layer)
    464                           output_shapes=[self.outputs[0]._keras_shape])
    465         else:
--> 466             output_tensor = layer(self.outputs[0])
    467             if isinstance(output_tensor, list):
    468                 raise TypeError('All layers in a Sequential model '

C:\Users\david\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\keras\layers\recurrent.py in __call__(self, inputs, initial_state, **kwargs)
    241         # modify the input spec to include the state.
    242         if initial_state is None:
--> 243             return super(Recurrent, self).__call__(inputs, **kwargs)
    244 
    245         if not isinstance(initial_state, (list, tuple)):

C:\Users\david\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\topology.py in __call__(self, inputs, **kwargs)
    539                 # Raise exceptions in case the input is not compatible
    540                 # with the input_spec specified in the layer constructor.
--> 541                 self.assert_input_compatibility(inputs)
    542 
    543                 # Collect input shapes to build layer.

C:\Users\david\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\topology.py in assert_input_compatibility(self, inputs)
    438                                      self.name + ': expected ndim=' +
    439                                      str(spec.ndim) + ', found ndim=' +
--> 440                                      str(K.ndim(x)))
    441             if spec.max_ndim is not None:
    442                 ndim = K.ndim(x)

ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer lstm_24: expected ndim=3, found ndim=4
```

I appreciate the help

Answer (score 1):

It's because of shape error of first layer and second layer. You need to add return_sequences=True into first layer.

Like

`model.add(LSTM(32,input_shape=(1,1),return_sequences=True))`

Answer (score 0):

It means the first layers is outputting a tensor with 4 dimensions, while the LSTM layer is expecting a three dimension tensor as input.

To solve that you could simply change the input_shape of dense. I suppose something like `input_shape=(Timesteps, DataLength)`, where `Timesteps * DataLength = nrows*ncols*nchan` would be ok.

You'd probably benefit from adding a `Reshape((Timesteps,DataLength))` layer before everything, so you can reshape data properly for the next layers.

Now, it's up to you to decide what you consider to be the timesteps in (nrows,ncols,nchan)

Comment: Looks like LSTM does not support 3D input, I will have to reshape or try something else.